# How to subset my dataframe in R with these 2 conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

Suppose I have a data frame (called mydata1) with 6 columns having headers A to F.

I need to create a new data set with columns A, C and F but only with rows where F >= 100.

I am new to R and the way I am doing it is in a 2 step process:

Step 1:

```
library (dplyr)
mydata2 %>% select(A, C, F)
```

Step 2:

```
mydata3[mydata2$F >= 100, ]
```

Is there a way to do it in 1 single step and have only mydata2 as the final data set?

Comment: In base R it is just `mydata2[mydata2$F >= 100, c('A','C','F')]`

Comment: Shouldn't that be mydata1$F?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're almost there. you just have to take the `filter` verb (that does the row subsetting) and chain it all together. See the [data transformation chapter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html) in Hadley Wickham's book.

```
mydata2 <- mydata1 %>%
  filter(F >= 100) %>%
  select(A, C, F)
```

Comment: Is this expression (F == 100) the same as F being greater or equal to 100?

Comment: oh sorry. I misread your question. Of course you were correct with >=. I edited my response accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

just use base R and notice the quotes

```
   mydata2= mydata[mydata$F>100,c("A","C","F")]
```